# validation error message keeps repeating every time I submit the form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have started by trying to hide the message class and then only show the message if there is an error. It works fine the first time I submit the form but if I submit again, it shows the error next to the original error. If I click again, I then have 3 x the same error message.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".message").hide();
            $("#submit").on('click', function(){
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'php/functions.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    data: {name: name, email: email},
                    })

                .done(function(data) {

                    console.log(data);

                    if(! data.success) {

                        if(data.errors.name) {
                            $( "#error-name" ).append(data.errors.name).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: you can empty it first: `$( "#error-name" ).empty().append(data.errors.name).show()` or just repalce everything inside:  `$( "#error-name" ).html(data.errors.name).show()`

Comment: That does the trick! But if I fill the text field in the error should go away but it still stays there.

Comment: There really isnt enough information here for me to go on but you can attach an on change event to the text input that hides the error message when the fields value is changed.